# Images are broken in Wysiwyg Editor - ACF backend

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, editor, wysiwyg

I work in the local environment WAMP, and images are visible on the frontend.
When I enter to the backend Wysiwyg Editor they are broken

Links look like that

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="wp-content/themes/Root/assets/images/oculus.png" alt="Image" /></div>
```

How i can solve this?

Comment: Well I guess you just need to use the full absolute path relative to your site's home page (e.g. `/wp-content/themes/...`) or just use the full URL (e.g. `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/...`).

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried that, and I will try it again. I think that then pictures doesn't appears on the frontend.

Comment: Ignore my previous (deleted) comments and if you're sure you've tried using `/wp-content/` (note the leading slash - `/`) and also the complete URL having the domain name, and none worked, then *maybe* there's a typo in the path or URL. Try also clearing your caches.

Comment: @SallyCJ it works now with full path, its localhost wamp server.